# How to add a wildcard to a sql string in c# that takes data from a TextBox

Tags: c#, sql, oledb

I want to add the wild card `%` to the end of the string from my `TextBox` but I'm not sure of the syntax. This is my code.

```
OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("SELECT * FROM Patient WHERE FirstName LIKE '"+tbSearch.Text+"'",conn);
```

After `tbSearch` I want to add the wildcard

Comment: `'"+tbSearch.Text+"'` WARNING: [SQL INJECTION](http://www.unixwiz.net/techtips/sql-injection.html) ATTACK!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should be like this:

```
SELECT * FROM Patient WHERE FirstName LIKE '"+tbSearch.Text+"%'
```

But I strongly recommend that you always use [parameterized queries](http://blog.codinghorror.com/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death/) to avoid [SQL Injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection). Like this:

```
OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("SELECT * FROM Patient WHERE FirstName LIKE @Search",conn);
cmd.Parameters.Add("@Search", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = tbSearch.Text + "%";
```

Comment: Yeah, although this looks like a WinForms application, so it seems like the user has full DB access anyway...

Comment: This is a very simple program for college so no worries about SQL Injections however its good to know for future reference

Comment: @JerryMurphy...BTW You should always use parameterized queries.

Comment: @S.Akbari I will look into them. Just going reading that ling you sent me there. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

The correct way is to use a parameterized query like this one

```
OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("SELECT * FROM Patient WHERE FirstName LIKE @name",conn);
cmd.Parameters.Add("@name", OleDbType.VarWChar).Value = tbSearch.Text + "%";
OleDbDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
......
```

Using parameters is of fundamental importance to avoid Sql Injection but also subtle errors caused by the string concatenation. If your tbSearch contains a name with a single quote (O'Brian for example), the string concatenation causes an invalid text to be passed to the database parser and a Syntax Error exception follows.

Answer (score 0):

- Never use `Select *`, specify the column name - this will avoid troubles if someone uses indexers, and later on columns get changed/added/deleted.
- Always use parameterized SQL or stored procedures or LINQ
- Finally, answer to your question is simple, you need to remember that the wildcard is also part of the actual query that you want to send to SQL engine, so it would be

> `FirstName LIKE '"+ tbSearch.Text + "%'

==> You are simply adding the % right after the variable - in this case the Text of the textbox.